# Use a gesture inside a scrollview (bring content out of the scrollview by means of gestures)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, subview, uigesturerecognizer

Inside my UIScrollView I've got a view. Within this view there are several images. I'd like to drag the images out of my scroller (and view) to the mainview. However getting the images in front of the scroller and view is driving me bonkers.

This is a piece of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    //scroller properties
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1300, 130);
    scroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled =YES;
    scroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 874, 768, 130);
    [scroller setDelegate:self];

    UIView *contentContainer = [[UIView alloc] init];

    [scroller addSubview:contentContainer];
    [scroller addSubview:image1];
    [scroller bringSubviewToFront:image1];
    [speler1 release];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress1 =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
    [image1 addGestureRecognizer:longPress1];
    [longPress1 release];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [image1 addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];


}

-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [[self.view superview] bringSubviewToFront:image1];

}

-(void)move:(id)sender {

    //move the image

}
```

I'd like to bring the images in front of the views by using a LongPressGestureRecognizer. The PanGestureRecognizer takes care of moving the image. The dragging works only inside the scrollview. Anyone knows how to bring my images in front of the views?

Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Next time you should choose better tags. This will greatly improve the visibility of your question. If nobody finds your question nobody will answer it.

Comment: thanks I'll keep it reminded!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded with putting the image from the scroller to the main view. See my code below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    //scroller properties
    scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1300, 130);
    scroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scroller.directionalLockEnabled =YES;
    scroller.frame = CGRectMake(0, 874, 768, 130);
    [scroller setDelegate:self];
    [scroller addSubview:image1];

    [image1 release];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress1 =
    [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
    [image1 addGestureRecognizer:longPress1];
    [longPress1 release];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]  initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [image1 addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];


}

-(void)longPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:image1];
    image1.center = location;
}

-(void)move:(id)sender {

    //move the image
}
```

Now I'd like to be able to put my images back to my scrollview. I'm trying to implement this by means of touchesended and a doubletap. The image will be placed to it's origin. However it won't go back inside the scroller. Here's a piece of the touchedended method.

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.20];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        image1.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        image1.center = CGPointMake(20, 20);

        [self.view sendSubviewToBack:image1];

        return;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can point me in the right direction for putting the image back inside my scroller at the same location where it came from.

Thanks in advance!